# How do I create one search bar in springboot for two separate things? It should be able to accept first name, or last name, or both to give an output

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, searchbar

I have a search bar that can accept any string. It will check the database to see if a record matches the string either in their first name or last name. But it should also be able to take the full name as an argument and return the records based on it.

I take the fullName as an argument and split it to create a separate first and last name and used an if statement to check it matches. But it doesn't seem to work although I cannot see an issue with the logic.

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
private final EmployeeService empService;

@Autowired
public EmployeeController(EmployeeService empService) {
    this.empService = empService;
}

@PostMapping("search-by-full-name")
public String handleSearchByFullName(Model model, @RequestParam("fullName") String fullName) {
    if (fullName.contains(" ")) {
        String[] nameParts = fullName.split(" ");
        String firstName = nameParts[0];
        String lastName = nameParts[1];
        for (Employee emp : empService.findByFullName(fullName)) {
            if (emp.getFirstName().equals(firstName) && emp.getLastName().equals(lastName)) {
                model.addAttribute("emps", empService.findByFirstName(firstName));
                return "showEmployees";
            }
        }
    } else if (!empService.findByFullName(fullName).isEmpty()) {
        model.addAttribute("emps", empService.findByFullName(fullName));
        return "showEmployees";
    }
    return "errorPage";
}
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
private final EmployeeRepository empRepo;

@Autowired
public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository empRepo) {
    this.empRepo = empRepo;
}

public List<Employee> findByFullName(String fullName) {
    return empRepo.findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(fullName, fullName);
}

public List<Employee> findByFirstName(String firstName) {
    return empRepo.findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCase(firstName);
}

public List<Employee> findByLastName(String lastName) {
    return empRepo.findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(lastName);
}
```

}

Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends 
JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
List<Employee> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String firstName, String lastName);

List<Employee> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCase(String firstName);

List<Employee> findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String lastName);
```

}

Comment: Why? You already have a query which limits this and still do an if check? What is the purpose of the query then? Also why re-fetch the entities? You already have them, why on earth are you executing the same/other query again?

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not really sure what you are asking to be honest because I posted this question to get help. This is the code after a lot of trial and error so I would appreciate if you gave me a helpful reply rather than asking why on earth I am doing anything because my answer is I. Don't. Know. I need the single search bar to be able to search the full name of a record and give it. Right now it only returns if I search a first name that matches a record or a last name that matches a record. It fails to check that both the first name and last name inputs match a record.

Comment: If 1 element (no spaces) call a method that queries for either firstname or lastname matches. If 2 elements call a method that querier for matches on firstname **and** lastname. Just 2 methods, which return a list. No need to re-run queries, use equals etc. You are basically overthinking all of this.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you edit my controller code to emulate this please? Because it sounds a lot like what I am already trying to do.

Comment: No you are doing way too much and (as mentioned) overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

Check name for spaces. If space available, get first part as firstname the remainder as lastname. Call query methods with 2 parameters using an `and`, else use `name` parameter as is and call method with 2 parameters using an `or`.

Your code is overthinking all of this with additional checks and queries. Move the logic to the service instead of in your controller.

```java
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

List<Employee> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name, String name);

List<Employee> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCaseAndLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String firstname, String lastname);
```

```java
@Service
public EmployeeService {

  private final EmployeeRepository employees;

  public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employees) {
    this.employees=employees;
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly=true)
  public List<Employee> findEmployees(String name) {
    var idx = name.indexOf(' ');
    if (idx > -1) {
      var firstname = name.substring(0, idx);
      var lastname = name.substring(idx + 1);
      return employees. findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCaseAndLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(firstname, lastname);      
    }
    return employees. findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(name, name);      
  }
}
```

Now in your controller just call the `findEmployees` method.

```java
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

private final EmployeeService empService;

  public EmployeeController(EmployeeService empService) {
    this.empService = empService;
  }

  @PostMapping("search-by-full-name")
  public String handleSearchByFullName(Model model, @RequestParam("fullName") String fullName) {
    
    model.addAttribute("emps", empService.findEmployees(fullName));
    return "showEmployees";
  }
}
```

Something like this.